# WPF - ComboBox with Button items

Tags: c#, wpf, button, combobox

I have this combobox and I wanted to add buttons as items in it. However, when I select the button from the combobox and click on the button, the action is not executed. The combobox's list falls instead. How should do this? If this is not possible, I think I'll just have to improvise. Suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you!

```html
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBoxItem Name="Item1">
    <Button Name="Button1" Click="Button1_OnClick">first button</Button>
  </ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem Name="Item2">
    <Button Name="Button2" Click="Button2_OnClick">second button</Button>
  </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need ItemTemplate, like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CB" Width="150" ItemsSource="{BindingItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And you need the event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Do something
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the quick response... Does this mean that the bound buttons all have the same event handler? I wanted to have different handlers for the buttons.

Comment: @MachoGwapito No, it's button can have a different event handler if you want. Or even the same as i said.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I had an "aha!" moment earlier thanks to your answer. :D Again. Thank you!